# counting various instances within a list

Tags: python

I've hit a wall here for a project i'm completing. i've tried while loops, for loops, counts etc.
i need to count instances of numbers eg. (<=10)(>10 & <=20) etc etc

```
data=[99,50,19,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,64,69,59,17,22]

while grades >=10:
    counter=0
for grades in data:
    grades[counter]=grades+1
    counter+=1
```

This isnt the only attempt, rather this was my last attempt before i lost my head.

i've encountered many threads here which havent solved this. it more than likely just me

Will appreciate any help

edit - i wasnt clear, as advised by the below user.
i require my results to look something similar to the below

```
grades <= 10 - 2
grades >10 & <=20 - 5
grades >20 & <=30 - 7
etc
etc
etc
```

Comment: Please update your question with some expected outputs.

Comment: The `while` loop doesn't make sense.  It's testing `grades`, over and over, even though `grades` does not appear to be set.  If `grades` is defined, the loop will either be infinite or else not execute at all.  Following this is a `for` loop, which tries to index into `grades`, suggesting it's now a `list` or a `dict`, but then it tries to add 1 to `grades` without any indexing, which implies `grades` is a number.  Try to come up with a plan for what your variables hold and how you want to use them.

Comment: Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: you could put the conditions you want to use to select elements from data in simple list comprehensions, e.g. `data_ge_10 = [x for x in data if x >= 10]` - no need for imports or complicated loops.

Comment: cheers. i'll give this a go once i'm home. dont want to use imports as this will need to be given elsewhere who may not have the import data.

Answer (score 0):

Using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

data=np.array([99,50,19,67,85,87,50,45,51,72,64,69,59,17,22])

len(data[(data>20) & (data<=30)])
#result: 1
len(data[(data>=10)])
#result: 15
```

Comment: A bit late to reply but thanks for your answer. I can confirm this worked as intended

Comment: No worries:) please mark it as an answer then to close off your question